# which preposition is correct ? "to" or "for" ? and Why?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know why we must use the preposition "to" instead of "for" in the following sentence
Thanks

Is there a loophole "to" some of these requirements?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't.

The correct version is:

> Is there a loophole *in* some of these requirements?

See the [example sentences here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loophole), and [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loophole?s=t).

The word loophole originally referred to a real hole. Hole occur *in* things, not *to* or *for* things. (Although in fairness it should be said that sometimes prepositions in English are pretty arbitrary.)

Obviously there are sentences in which 'to' can be used with *loophole*, but they have a different meaning, such as:

> He used a loophole to avoid paying his taxes.

Comment: Sorry, I heard "Is there a loophole "to" some of these requirements?" from a native speaker of English so I am sure "to" is correct.
Can you explain why ?
Thaks

Comment: Follow the link to the example sentences.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. It seems you can also say "in". However, I ve seen "to" used in replacement of "to" and this is what I d like to understand. I am sure "Is there a loophole "to" some of these requirements?" is acceptable.

Here s another  example
"Christoph Meinel and Larry Leifer assert that there are four principles "to" design thinking"

Why "to" design thinking and not ""in" design thinking" ?
The original version is with "to"
Thanks

Comment: Just because you've seen it doesn't mean its correct. As for your other question, please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I am not trying to be correct, I am trying to figure out what s acceptable for native speakers, even if it s not approved by Webster Dictionary
Thanks

Comment: Lots of prepositions would work if you aren't trying to be correct.

Comment: @tongue2016 Lots of native speakers make mistakes while speaking. And I don't mean mistakes that a prescriptivist would call them out on, but rather mistakes that they themselves would agree are wrong, but at the time couldn't be bothered to correct. Think about how you speak your own language and whether sometimes when speaking you don't make mistakes that you don't bother correcting.